# Cannot resolve method addsnapshot listener in android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I am getting the following error "Cannot resolve method addSnapshotListener(com.example.cleanerapp.Todaybooking, anonymous com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener<com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot>)". How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `this` as the first argument and let only the `EventListener` implementation.

The `addSnapshotListener` doesn't expect the activity as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It can resolve the method, but the signature is another, because you pass wrong arguments.
Do what it says and pass an instance of `Java.util.concurrentExecutor` as the first argument.

Comment: You don't need an Executor to perform Firebase calls, it alredy manage the threads by itself.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try this:

```
   Todaybooking data =  documentSnapshot.toObject(Todaybooking.class);
```

or maybe you should check the hardcoded strings